# native dos batch - find variable value in a text file and store the value in an external txt file

Tags: batch-file

there is a txt file of arbitraty lenght (usually above 100kb) and I need to extract the value of a particular variable that is apearing somwhere in the text as:

```
"variable name": "variable value"
```

in order and number of times as it apears in the original text (search trough) and echo the resault to > resault.txt

could someone help please?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your txt file in JSON format, by chance?  What version of DOS?

Comment: Are you truly running on an old DOS machine? or are you using Windows?

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own so far? please share your efforts!

Comment: yes it looks like JSON format.

Comment: Ever tried find command? (not the MSYS one, the native MS-DOS one that (roughly) acts like grep, only less powerful. Something like `find "variable" myfile > result.txt`could work